# Xamarin DependencyService: System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for [Interface]

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, stripe.net

I am receiving this error when using the Dependency Service on a `Xamarin.Forms PCL`. I have seen answers to this error that involve `iOS` and the `Linker`.
However, I am running this on `Android` and the `Linker` is off. Debug mode as well.

*The constructor it is telling me it cannot find the default constructor for the Interface in the PCL.*

I thought it may have been an issue with some renaming I did (I used refactor tool and made sure all necessary changes were being made) so I deleted those folders/files and remade them. Still nothing :(

I have been searching and debugging this for hours. 
What are some things that could be causing this error? 
I am pretty sure my `DependencyService` Implementations are correct so I feel like it is something different.

Here is my related code.

#### Interface:

```
namespace Enchantum.Functions
{
public interface PaymentProcessor
{

    void setUpCard(String cardNumber,
        int expirationMonth,
        int expirationYear,
        String CVC);

    Task cardTokenizer();

    void backendCardCharge();

}
```

#### Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PaymentProcessor_Android))]

namespace Enchantum.Droid.Functions_Android
{
class PaymentProcessor_Android : PaymentProcessor
{
public PaymentProcessor_Android() { }

    private Card mCard;
    private Token mToken;

    public void setUpCard(String cardNumber, int expirationMonth,
        int expirationYear, String cvcCode)
    {
        Card card = new Card
        {
            Number = cardNumber,
            ExpiryMonth = expirationMonth,
            ExpiryYear = expirationYear,
            CVC = cvcCode
        };

        mCard = card;
    }

    public async Task cardTokenizer()
    {
        mToken = await StripeClient.CreateToken(mCard);
    }

    /*TODO: 
     * */

    public void backendCardCharge()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

#### iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PaymentProcessor_iOS))]

namespace Enchantum.iOS.Functions_iOS
{
class PaymentProcessor_iOS : PaymentProcessor
{
public PaymentProcessor_iOS() { }

    private Card mCard;
    private Token mToken;

    public void setUpCard(String cardNumber, int expirationMonth,
        int expirationYear, String cvcCode)
    {
        Card card = new Card
        {
            Number = cardNumber,
            ExpiryMonth = expirationMonth,
            ExpiryYear = expirationYear,
            CVC = cvcCode
        };

        mCard = card;

    }

    public async Task cardTokenizer()
    {
        mToken = await StripeClient.CreateToken(mCard);
    }

    /*TODO:*/
    public void backendCardCharge()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }




}
```

#### Implementation in a Xamarin.Form Content Page:

```
DependencyService.Get<PaymentProcessor>().setUpCard(
                    cardNumber,
                    expirationMonth,
                    expirationYear,
                    CVC);
```

**My error, again : "System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Enchantum.Functions.PaymentProcessor"**

What is going wrong?

**P.S.** Pardon my incorrect naming convention for the Interface as well some other mess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you can try making your interface implementation classes `public`, your constructors are visible, but the class itself might not be.

So Like:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PaymentProcessor_Android))]

namespace Enchantum.Droid.Functions_Android
{
public class PaymentProcessor_Android : PaymentProcessor //make the class public
{

 //your code here

 }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this and wonders why your code seems not quite right to this. The Dependency definition should include the current class, `PaymentProcessor_Android` not the interface, `PaymentProcessor`.

Comment: As in the example above, my mistake was to write `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PaymentProcessor))]` and I receive the same error.

Comment: In my case, the constructor was protected, changing it to public did the trick!

Comment: I was scratching my head for a while but it is essential to have that `[assembly: Dependency(typeof([Your_Type))]` line. I don't know if all resolvers require this line so this might have slipped by me, but the Xamarin Forms one does.

Comment: @BradMoore - Correct answer for me... Had the interface instead of the class. Once changed, it worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: So I had a combination of having the Interface name in the `assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency` argument which you should have class name. Additionally having a constructor defined in the class `public PaymentProccessor_Android() {}` also cause an issue because the interface doesn't have that constructor defined in it

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the problem was in the assembly exportation line.
The app was crashing as I used interface type instead of the class implementation:
`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IServiceType))]`

But the **correct way** is to use **Platform-Specific** implementation of the interface:
`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ServiceImplementation_Android))]`

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue for Linker , When I set Linker to None its working

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I defined a default constructor that initialized a **readonly** private property.

Seemed crazy, but it makes sense given Java doesnt have a concept of readonly, and the property probably transpiled to a constant.